# Uppercase letters and numbers in mathjax are too big

Tags: mathjax

I'm setting up a webpage in Github using Jekyll. I've implemented Mathjax in order to render mathematical text. My configuration is minimal:

```
<!-- Mathjax -->
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to-mathjax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
  src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
```

It works fine, except for the fact that inline math text and uppercase letters look to big, considering the surrounding text. I set up [this page](https://acarril.github.io/2015/05/mathjax-test.html) as an example.

So far the only thing I've been able to do is to scale down the math by a factor of the surrounding text, by using

```
"HTML-CSS": {
scale: 90
}
```

The problem is that it scales all math expressions, including lowercase letters that seem to have the right size without scaling.

So my question is if there is a way to fix this discrepancy.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is ... there is a way to fix this discrepancy?

No.  MathJax matches the surrounding font by scaling its own fonts so that the ex-height matches that of the surround font.  That means that lower-case letters should be approximately equal in height, as is shown in your example.  So MathJax is correctly determining the ex-height of the surrounding and matching that.

The reason the capitals don't match is that different fonts have different ratios between the heights of the upper- and lower-case letters.  So if you get the lowercase letters to match, the uppercase ones will not (and *vice versa*).  With fonts that have a different uppercase-to-lowercase height ratio than the MathJax fonts, you won't be able to get both to match the surrounding font.  That is inherent in the design of the two fonts.

The only other possibility would be to scale the uppercase letters differently from the lowercase ones, but that would mean the weights would not match, and the quality of the math layout would suffer.

So, no, you can't get both, in general.

---

**Edit 30 April 2020:**

In the comment below we discuss the meaning of the `em` unit, which is the same as the (computed) `font-size` for the font.  Unfortunately, that is not the same as the height of the capital letters in the font.  For example, the code below shows an M inside a red box of height and width 1em and an x inside a box of height and width 1ex for the fonts Times, Courier, Impact, and Zapfino.  Run it to see the results.

```css
div {
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 120px;
}
em-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1em; height: 1em;
  margin-right: -1em;
}
ex-box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  width: 1ex; height: 1ex; 
  margin-right: -1ex;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
M-box {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1em;
}
x-box {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 1ex;
}
```

```html
<div style="font-family: Times">
<em-box></em-box><M-box>M</M-box><ex-box></ex-box><x-box>x</x-box>
</div>
<div style="font-family: Courier">
<em-box></em-box><M-box>M</M-box><ex-box></ex-box><x-box>x</x-box>
</div>
<div style="font-family: Impact">
<em-box></em-box><M-box>M</M-box><ex-box></ex-box><x-box>x</x-box>
</div>
<div style="font-family: Zapfino">
<em-box></em-box><M-box>M</M-box><ex-box></ex-box><x-box>x</x-box>
</div>
```

Here is an image in case you can't view the results above.

[image]

Note that the em boxes (red) are the same in all cases, and are the height specified in the CSS (50px), whereas the height of the M varies within that box (whereas the height of the x matches its box).  So the em-size can't be used to tell the height of the capital letters in the font.

I don't know of a way to determine the actual height of the M.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Then, is there a sans serif font has the same ratio between the height of uppercase and lowercase as the font used by Mathjax?

Comment: I haven't done any analysis of fonts to determine this.  Of course, the MathJax_SansSerif-Regular font should match.  It would be possible to use that for the text if you don't need anything outside the ASCII range.

Comment: I know that MathJax matches lower-case letters by default. Is it possible to use automatic font size matching but match upper case `M` instead?

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, no, at least not automatically.  The information about the height of the M is not available (while the height of the x is).  The font-relative using of `ex` is the height of an `x` in the font, and MathJax can use that to determine the height to use.  The font-relative unit `em` is the *width* of the M, not its height, and there are no other font-relative units, so MathJAx can't determine the height of the M.  You could turn off the font matching and set the MathJax scaling factor by hand, however.  But you'd have to figure out the scale any trial and error.

Comment: Yes, traditionally in typography "em" means the width of letter "M". However, in context of web browsers, the unit `em` means font-size which in practise is the same as height of letter "M". See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#em

Comment: I'm trying to figure if there's a way to make the output look nice when MathJax is used for chem formulas that usually use lots of upper case letters. I understand that in that case lower case letters will be sized incorrectly but the overall line height would look more stable.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen, you are correct about `em` in web browsers (and MathJax does use that to obtain the `em` size).  Unfortunately, the `em` size (and the `font-size`) is not the same as the height of an M as you claim.  I have added an example to my answer to illustrate this.  Unfortunately, I don't see a way to determine the height of the capitals programmatically.  The best I can suggest is that you use the `scale` configuration option to adjust the size of the output to better match your environment.  You may want to set `matchFontHeight` to false as well.

Comment: I stand corrected about the height of `M`. Is there a way to adjust scale per formula in case I have multiple formulas on the same page and only some of those need special handling?

Comment: The only way that I can think of would be to wrap the math in a span that sets the `font-size`.  You could use a class to do that.